# Multiple select question on finding square root of $-1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

This is a multiple select question.

The values of $i$ where $i$ is square root is $-1$ is

$a$ - $e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$

$b$ - $e^{\frac{-\pi}{2}}$

$c$ - $e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$

$d$ - $e^{\frac{-i\pi}{2}}$

This is my attempt.

Since $i$ = $-1$ therefore $i^2$ = $-1$.

As $e^x$ is real for every real $x$. Therefore $a$ and $b$ are discarded.

Now using $e^{ix} = cosx + isinx$, I get that  $e^{\frac{-i\pi}{2}}$ and  $e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$ = $i$ and there $c$ and $d$ should be the correct answers.

But answer sheet shows only $c$.

Please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, only c) is correct. Note that$$\exp\left(-\frac{\pi i}2\right)=\cos\left(-\frac\pi2\right)+\sin\left(-\frac\pi2\right)i=-i.$$

Comment: You might want to look at that again....

Comment: @Paul I did. And I didn't like what I saw. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't $-i$ a square root of $-1$?

Comment: Yes. It's one of them. The other one is $i$.

Comment: and your question asks for a way of writing $i$, not find the roots of $-1$

Comment: The question says to find the value of $i$ where $i$ is a square root of $-1$. So we have to find value of square root of $-1$ which is $i$ as well as $-i$

Comment: If you say that, then you have no clue about what the complex numbers are.

Comment: Don't we just need to find the value of square root of $-1$ here? which infact I guess is just $i$?

Comment: The number $-1$ has *two* square roots: $i$ and $-i$.